# How to create binary relation matrix with R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data.frame that looks like this.For example:

```
A;a 
B;a 
C;b 
D;c
A;b
A;d
C;c
```

First pos = key , second pos = value. If key; value , then 1 ,if not then 0;

I would to create binary matrix from data, I would like to have this table format:

```
0 a b c d
A 1 1 0 1  
B 1 0 0 0
C 0 1 1 0
D 0 0 0 1
```

I could create matrix ,but not binary martix , because some lines are repeat
My code:

```
 mydb2 <- structure(list(Key = c("A","B","C","D","E","A","A"), 
                   Value = c("b","c","e","a","f","g","g")), 
              .Names = c("", ""), class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA, -6L))
table(mydb2)
```

And out

[image]

how can I fix it?

Comment: You have to put some effort into your question, what steps have you taken? SO is not an "Ask, and give me answers" FAQ. You gotta try. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I agree, what have you tried?

Comment: *I would like to have this table format* ; try `?table`

Comment: `table(dt$V1,dt$V2)` ?

Comment: I read data from .txt file. I wrote data so

Comment: I got to buid a matrix ,but my matrix not binary,because my datas  some lines(Key and Value) are repeated, How can I correct mistake

Comment: @Dossan ; have you managed to read you data in correctly? If so, can you add it to your question please (you can do this by adding the results of `dput(yourdataframe)` - just to make sure everything else is okay) thanks . ps you can remove duplicate rows using `unique` on your dataframe, or convert all positive integers to one using logical operations (ie `(yourtable > 0) + 0`

Comment: Thanks for update. Two options : 1. Use logical operations to convert >1 value to 1: `tab = table(mydb2) ; (tab > 0 ) + 0`, 2. Remove duplicate rows before tabling `table(unique(mydb2))`

Comment: Thank u very much, your comment helped me. I have database on txt file in this format:for example :  A;a (next line)  B;a  (next line) B;c  (next line) .....            How can i get data from file to list(  Key  = c( here), Value = c(here) )?

Answer (score 1):

As @Wen pointed out in comments, read the data from file (containing no header line):

```
> t = read.table('test.txt',sep=';')
> t
  V1 V2
1  A  a
2  B  a
3  C  b
4  D  c
5  A  b
6  A  d
7  C  c
```

and use `table` command and convert it to binary matrix by updating all elements having values larger than 1 into value 1:

```
> t2 <- table(t$V1,t$V2)
> t2[t2 > 1] <- 1
> t2

    a b c d
  A 1 1 0 1
  B 1 0 0 0
  C 0 1 1 0
  D 0 0 1 0
```